# Implement Interface with the member of another interface on a Discriminated Union

Tags: generics, interface, f#, f#-argu

I am using Argu to parse my cli arguments. I noticed that I need the same arguments for two different things. I would like to use the same types and only change the interface implementation (IArgParserTemplate on my Argument Discriminated Union).

something along the lines of this:

```
type IArgumentDescription =
     abstract member FirstDescription: string

type ImportArguments =
    interface IArgumentDescription with
        member this.FirstDescription = "Import Description"

type ExportArguments =
    interface IArgumentDescription with
        member this.FirstDescription = "Export Description"

type Arguments<'T when 'T :> IArgumentDescription> = | FirstArgument of string
with 
    interface IArgParserTemplate with
        member this.Usage =
            match this with
            | FirstArgument _ -> ? (Here I would like to use the 'T.FirstDescription of the IArgumentDescription Interface. (this:>IArgumentDescription).FirstDescription does not work.)
```

Is this even possible in FSharp and if yes what is the correct syntax?

Comment: You don't have an instance of `'T` whose `FirstDescription` member you could use.

Comment: But isn't `this` of `type Arguments<IArgumentDescription>`?

Comment: Yes. But `IArgumentDescription` is only a type parameter; it's not *implemented* by this type.

Comment: As DU also do not support Object Expressions, is there another way of implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a good way to do this, as you can't really parameterize or "subclass" a discriminated union. You could use a somewhat dirty hack involving reflection, but I'm not really sure that's advisable (as with most things related to reflection in production code).

```ml
type IArgParserTemplate =
    abstract member Usage : string


type IArgumentDescription =
     abstract member FirstDescription: string

// The parentheses are important to make this a class, not an interface
type ImportArguments() =
    interface IArgumentDescription with
        member this.FirstDescription = "Import Description"

// The parentheses are important to make this a class, not an interface
type ExportArguments() =
    interface IArgumentDescription with
        member this.FirstDescription = "Export Description"

type Arguments<'T when 'T :> IArgumentDescription> = | FirstArgument of string
with 
    interface IArgParserTemplate with
        member this.Usage =
            // Here's your instance of 'T
            let instance = Activator.CreateInstance<'T>()

            match this with
            | FirstArgument _ -> instance.FirstDescription
```

Comment: Do you think keeping it explicit would be the better way to go? Having two separate Argument types implementing the descriptions separately?

Comment: Turns out Argu does not support generic DUs at all so all of this is mute. Thank you anyway @TeaDrivenDev